# How to declare a a two dimentional string array in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I need help to what seems to be a simple task, but I cannot find how to do this.

I have a form and a button.
In the 'button_click' event I want to declare an array like - String myArray [20,50]-

Then I want to populate the array withlines of text that I am reading from a ,txt file. That is, 50 line X 20 character. (I know how to read the file)

Could anyone show me the correct syntax/method
to get this working.

Comment: C++ is usually not the best language to figure out as you go; I would recommend looking for books or tutorials online.

Comment: You probably want something like `std::array<std::array<String,20>50> myArray;`

Comment: Go run through some tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initializing a 2 dimensional array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612328/initializing-a-2-dimensional-array-of-strings)

Comment: A string already contains multiple characters; a 2D array of strings would have three dimensions for characters. Additionally, C++ doesn’t have 2-dimensional arrays *per se*; it has arrays of arrays. I would recommend either `std::array<std::array<char, 20>, 50>` or `char[20][50]`.

Comment: @FrancescoC read [ask].

Comment: Prefer `std::array` or `std::vector` over C-style arrays in most (almost all) cases.

Comment: Hi, the syntax of your suggestions gives a lot of errors. I think that is plain C++. I need code for VIsual C++  following - private void closeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)-   Then I would declare my array .

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to declare a two *dimentional* [sic] array of strings:

**Strings**

```
std::string matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > matrix_vectors;
std::array< std::array<std::string> >  matrix_array;
std::string matrix[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS];
```

**C-Style strings**
A C-Style string is an array of `char` terminated by a nul, `'\0'`, character.

Since it is an array, we'll be create a 3 dimensional array of characters:

```
char matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```